# php cache expire in every certain number of page view

Tags: php, caching, load

I am looking for some information about caching a php. All info i found are to cache a php file in certain time interval (every some hours). Is there any way to cache for every 50 page views? After every 50 page views, the cached file should expire.

Anyone has any idea about this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In php we've got third-party caching. which one do you use?

Comment: Hi PLB, i'm still looking for information, the reference link i found is http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/php-caching.php , but it talks about caching every sometimes, not every some page views. What are the third party caching are you mentioning about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a solution ive just put together, instead of using a file based cache use a database, PDO sqlite (This way its easy just to delete the cache file database to clear all cache).

Look towards the bottom you can see how it works, it will delete the row after 50 hits and redirect so it can generate a new copy. Hope it helps

**sqlite.cache.class.php**

```
<?php 
/**
* PDO sqlite cache class
* You can include('sqlite.cache.class.php'); this class
*/
class sqlite_cache{
    private $db;

    function __construct($dsn){
        $this->dsn = $dsn;
        $this->chkSetup();
    }

    /*Singleton Connect*/
    private function connect(){
        if (!$this->db instanceof PDO){
            $this->db = new PDO($this->dsn);
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }

    /*Raw Select*/
    public function rawSelect($sql){
        $this->connect();
        return $this->db->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function get($fieldname=null, $id=null){
        $this->connect();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cache WHERE $fieldname = :id";
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    /*Insert*/
    public function put($values){
        $this->connect();
        $fieldnames = array_keys($values[0]);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO cache ";
        $fields = '('.implode(' ,', $fieldnames).')';
        $bound = '(:'.implode(', :', $fieldnames).')';
        $sql .= $fields.' VALUES '.$bound;

        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        foreach($values as $vals){
            $statement->execute($vals);
        }
    }

    /*Update*/
    public function update($fieldname, $value, $pk, $id){
        $this->connect();
        $sql = "UPDATE cache SET $fieldname = :value WHERE $pk = :id";
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':value', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
    }

    /*Update Hits*/
    public function add_hit($id){
        $this->connect();
        $sql = "UPDATE cache SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE url = :id";
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
    }

    /*Delete*/
    public function delete($id){
        $this->connect();
        $sql = "DELETE FROM cache WHERE url = :id";
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
    }


    /*Database Setup*/
    private function chkSetup(){
        $dso = explode(':',$this->dsn);

        if(file_exists($dso[1])){
            return;
        }else{
            $this->connect();
            //Create Table
            $sql ="CREATE TABLE cache (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                            title TEXT,
                                            url TEXT,
                                            hits INTEGER,
                                            date INTEGER,
                                            contents TEXT)";
            $this->db->query($sql);
            header("refresh:0;url=./");
            die;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
include('sqlite.cache.class.php');
$cache = new sqlite_cache('sqlite:./cache.db');

//Check if cache exists
$cache_result = $cache->get('url',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
//Exists
if(!empty($cache_result)){
    //Add Hit
    $cache->add_hit($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    //Delete If over 50 hits
    if($cache_result[0]['hits']>=50){
        $cache->delete($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        die;
    }

    echo $cache_result[0]['contents'];
}else{
    //Generate your page contents ect
    ob_start();

    ///////////////////////////////
    //Your script code goes here
    ///////////////////////////////

    echo 'Your content';

    //End your script code/////////
    ///////////////////////////////
    $return = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    //Before output build values to put in cache
    $cache_contents = array(array('id'=>NULL,
                                  'title'=>'Page Title',
                                  'url'=>$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
                                  'hits'=>'0',
                                  'date'=>time(),
                                  'contents'=>$return));

    //Store cache
    $cache->put($cache_contents);
    echo $return;
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi Lawrence. Your method is almpost perfect except that after that certain number of of page view, when i refresh the page it shows a blank page, after i refresh one more time it can update the new content. So, is there any little bug with this big php file?

Comment: I added  `echo $return;` (Last line) in an edit after `$cache->put($cache_contents);
` did you include that. Its not so big as you can include() it ;p

Comment: Oh, i think i don't know how to use that php file properly. Actually, i just copy and paste the whole code into a php file mysite.com/test.php, then i edit http://google.com with my desired page, so when i open mysite.com/test.php in my browser, it shows the content of my desired page. Is this a wrong way of using your php codes?

Comment: Yes, the part where im grabbing google is just to get some content, im not sure how your scripts architecture but that part is where **your** scripts code should be. Ill rephrase the answer alittle.

Comment: np, it works the same as the file based cache but instead of inputting your content into a file it goes in a database.

Answer (score 0):

You could go really low tech to get a solution for this.

For each hit to your URL you could create a temporary file as a counter.  Using something like this -

```
// recursively remove a directory
function rrmdir($dir) {
    foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
          if(is_dir($file))
            rrmdir($file);
          else
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
    rmdir($dir);
} 



$fileCount = count(glob($tempfile_directory."/*"));
if ($fileCount >= $someLimit){
  rrmdir($tempfile_directory); // clear the counter
  mkdir($tempfile_directory);
  // clear the cached server data and refresh. 
}
touch($tempfile_directory . '/' . time()); // create a new dummy counter file
```

Recursive remove function borrowed from - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php#108113

When the number of files in `$tempfile_directory` is bigger or equal to `$someLimit`, the folder will be emptied and the cached data refreshed.

Comment: So, actually the $someLimit variable is not the number of page loads, is it? It is only the number of pages that has been cached, right?

Comment: No no...  `$someLimit` is the number of page views you want to allow before refreshing your cache data..